# How to disable the mouse in vi completely for raspbian stretch (and most likely debian)

Tags: vim, mouse, raspbian, vi, disable

I really like the almost "keyboard only" approach of vi (vim) - I also got very used to the "mark to copy" and "right-click to paste" feature in my terminal.

Now someone changed the default setting of vim (starting in raspbian stretch) once the full version is installed (apt-get install vi) so that as soon as the mouse is used to mark some text vi enters --visual-- mode.

Initially I edited my vimrc and inserted `set mouse-=a`  as often suggested in posts on this topic. For my Raspberry Pis this did not produce the desired result. EDIT: must have put the ~/.vimrc file in a wrong location. After two replies I tried again and this solves the issue - put `set mouse=` in your `~/.vimrc`

I also tried this in `/etc/vim/vimrc` - but also with no effect.

After some time searching additional config files I found

`/usr/share/vim/vim81/defaults.vim`

and commented the following passage out

```
if has('mouse')
  set mouse=a
endif
```

or used
`set mouse=`

at the very end.

That finally took care of Visual mode!

I'd like to ask if I could have done this in a more elegant way - e.g. through my vimrc.

Comment: The `defaults.vim` file is only loaded if you don't have a `~/.vimrc` in your home... If your mouse setting is enabled, one way you can figure out where that setting is coming from is with the command `:verbose set mouse?`, if you undo your changes, post the output of that command and I can try to help figure out how to reconfigure it...

Comment: Thanks! Guess I must have messed up my tries with the ~/.vimrc - I'll try again since this feels much more like it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

To disable the mouse completely, you can just use:

```
set mouse=
```

without anything after the `=`

This will **disable mouse support in all modes**. It should work as expected if you add it to your `vimrc`

Comment: Thanks - it works - don't know why it did not work before, I think I must have edited the .vimrc in another location.

Comment: Thanks to both filbranden and BeeJayF.  I didn't have a ~/.vimrc file, and merely creating it w/ "touch" was sufficient to return vi to "normal" defaults.